# joining 2 tables in order to get all the data from the second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables one for messages and one for replies.

I want to get the results in the form of a list just like we use it in emails, something like

1. Question

   - reply
   - reply
   - reply

If I have let say one question in the messages table with message_id=1 and 3 replies in the reply table with the reply_id=1.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM messages
RIGHT JOIN replies ON replies.reply_id=messages.message_id
WHERE messages.status='message' AND (messages.to='$username' OR messages.to='all') 
GROUP BY messages.message_id DESC";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

I am getting the data listed from the messages table ( 1 result ), I am also getting reply listed but the problem is that I am getting only one reply as a result although I have more of them.

Answer (score 1):

You group the rows by `message_id` - I assume you want ordering, so use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Have you checked if the selections exclude replies, perhaps by applying the SQL query against the database directly?

Comment: no i did not but it a very simple query, i think there is no need for that. i just need to compare 2 columns and if a row in one table matches a condition from another it should be listed. I get only one data somehow.

Comment: i am making a simple mistake and i am not sure where.

Comment: Are you sure, the `reply_id` is the foreign key of table `replies`? If I would model my data, `reply_id` would be the primary key of table `replies` and `messages_id` the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

it is ORDER BY , and not GROUP BY... and use [mysql_error](https://www.php.net/mysql_error) for search errors... and for result use [mysql_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) and if your results are more or equal 2 record, use this function like this:

```
while( $res = mysql_fetch_array($result , MYSQL_ASSOC)){
echo $res['colomn1'];
echo $res['colomn2'];
}
```

Comment: I have made a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f36f5/7 that is exactly how it hast to look like, the last entry should be on the first place. The only thing I need to make is to make 2 different messages from this list. Message_id 1 and 2. I think I need to make a double sql statement or something like that.

Comment: ... i do not know if I actually need 2 tables at all or not

Comment: SELECT * FROM messages
WHERE (messages.to='Jack' OR messages.from='jack')
ORDER BY messages.id DESC
Here, you can do WHERE (to='Jack' OR from='jack') because you aren't use the join... and i don't understand whant do you want... i would create to table... Question with colomn : ID , user , message ; and Answer : ID , ID_question , user , message...
So, for select the message, you can do "SELECT * FROM Answer WHERE ID_question = $id_question ORDER BY ID ASC;" so i would do as... but i don't understand what do you want :\ (it because my english is rubbish o.o)